# Adding elements to an associative array during a loop

Tags: php

I have this loop:

```
foreach ($tables as $table => $queries) {
                    foreach ($queries as $query) {
                        $insert = array($query['column'] => $query['value']);
                    }
```

The `$insert` associative array should be incremented of new elements each loop, so that the logical result woud be:

```
 $insert = array($query['column'] => $query['value'], $query['column'] => $query['value'] ...etc);
```

I tried using `$insert[]` and `$insert .=` and `$insert +=` but none of these give the expected result

Thanks for any help

Comment: you should also declare your `$insert = array();` on the top. so we don't look like bunch of lazy php developers who don't declare our variables before we use them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once the array's been defined, you have to use

```
$insert[$query['column']] = $query['value']; // sample #1
```

to specify a new key/value pair within the $insert array.

If you use

```
$insert[] = array(...); // sample #2
```

you'll just be inserting a new child array that contains a single key/value pair.

e.g. $insert before

```
$insert = array(
   'foo' => 'bar'
);
```

$insert after sample #1

```
$insert = array(
    'foo' => 'bar',
    'baz' => 'qux'
);
```

$insert after sample #2:

```
$insert = array(
   'foo' => 'bar'
   0 => array(
        'baz' => 'qux'
   )
);
```

Comment: insert after sample 2 is messed up don't you think?

Comment: you have `baz` inside another array. i am confused where u getting that structure from

Comment: baz/qux are the two bits of $query, basically.

Answer (score 5):

You are looking for this

```
$insert[] =
```

Comment: @DevZer0 he should continue with trying `$insert[]`, but add the equals to it, `$insert[] = `

Comment: ok so we think he didn't put the `=` sign for assignment, anyway +1

Comment: This is returning child arrays and as stated in my question this is not what I am looking for. Thanks anyway

Comment: @DevZer0 ;) anyway half is deserved anyway!

Answer (score 2):

To insert in array use:

```
$insert[] = array($query['column'] => $query['value']);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$insert = array();

foreach ($tables as $table => $queries) 
{

    foreach ($queries as $query) 
    {
            $insert[$query['column']] = $query['value'];      
    }

}
```